# Facebook SDK with android

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, google-play-services

I have integrated the `facebook sdk` version 3.22.0 with android for reporting the app installation, the `facebook` doc advises me to call the `com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(Context, String)` method to complete this, but it does not work and the log says **"No attribution id available to send to server."** with the `FacebookException`. I have debuged the `sdk` source and found when run into the code of the method `com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers.getAndroidId(Context)`, it checked the `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` method of the `com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil class`, but the result is null, so the `SDK` skip to send the request. Does the activateApp method have any relation with the google service? and how can I slove this issue? By the way, the google play service has already run on my device.

Comment: You should use v3.23.1 or v4 of the SDK which fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I have upgrade the version to v3.23.1 and the request can be send even if isGooglePlayServicesAvailable is null, but the app insights are not changed, Is there any delay? How long can I see the changes of the insights report after request processed?

Comment: By default insights data ends with the previous day, but you can drag the slider to include the current day as well for more real time data.

Comment: It seems to be ok now, Thanks very much.